# Right way to separate array specific values into another arrays

Tags: php, arrays

There is the following `array` in my application:

```
array (
    [item_name_1] => GTA V
    [item_quantity_1] => 4
    [item_price_1] => 5990
    [item_name_2] => Watch_Dogs
    [item_quantity_2] => 1
    [item_price_2] => 5990
)
```

I want to divide/split this `array` into two pieces like that:

```
array (
    [item_name_1] => GTA V
    [item_quantity_1] => 4
    [item_price_1] => 5990
)

array (
    [item_name_2] => Watch_Dogs
    [item_quantity_2] => 1
    [item_price_2] => 5990
)
```

If you didn't realized, I want to separate items suffixed by 1 and 2 – and successively – unto different matrices and I really don't see the best way to perform this. Maybe regex?

I already tried to play with `explode()` and `implode()`, but no success – I have no creativity enough to explore their best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$src = array (
    'item_name_1' => 'GTA V',
    'item_quantity_1' => 4,
    'item_price_1' => 5990,
    'item_name_2' => 'Watch_Dogs',
    'item_quantity_2' => 1,
    'item_price_2' => 5990,
);

$dest = array();

foreach($src as $k => $v) {
  $sfx = preg_replace('/.*?_([0-9]+)$/', '$1',$k);
  $dest[$sfx][$k] = $v;
}

print_r($dest);
```